# Why is Maid-chan voice actor listed as '???' in ending credits?

Tags: the-pet-girl-of-sakurasou

In Sakurasou no Pet na Kanojo ending credits Maid-chan's voice actor name is "? ? ?". Why is that?
[image: screenshot of the ending sequence]

Comment: The tag has to be at most 25 symbols so the full name of the series didn't fit. If you know what to do in such cases, please edit the tag accordingly.

Comment: The right thing to do in such cases is to come up with some tag which works temporarily (as you did) and then make a post on [meta](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/) asking what should be the final tag. I've taken the liberty of making the meta post [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/646/24). BTW interesting question; I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: I think it might be because she was a program.. :S

Comment: Maid-chan's voice was not programmatically generated - her voice actor was listed as Horie Yui in the last episode's credits. Horie Yui was also Akasaka Ryuunosuke's voice actor. As such, there's some speculation on the Japanese internet to the effect that hiding Maid-chan's VA's name was done to make it clear that Maid-chan was a separate and distinct character from Ryuunosuke, or something to that effect. I haven't found any official statements on the matter, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(I'm Japanese, so please excuse my English.)

Maid-chan's voice actor is Horie Yui, the same one as the Ryuunosuke.

This is the last episode's ending credit:

[image: Last episode credits]

She has a radio program  called 堀江由衣の天使のたまご (Horie Yui's Angel Egg)
where she talks about the "???" and how the anime staff asked her to keep it a secret in the the broadcast that aired on 2013/4/7 in Japan.

From the [unofficial text transcript](http://sakura-net.net/radio/tentama/tt_549.htm#free) of the broadcast.

I will reprint and translate only conclusion.

#### Japanese

> 結論から言いますと、**私にも、わかりません**。

#### English

> As it turns out, **I even, do not know**.

This is the official conclusion.

Comment: I guess this is as close as it gets to an authoritative answer.